# Google Chrome video streaming freeze fix?

Tags: google-chrome, video, ssd, streaming

I have a fresh new Windows 10 install with the latest drivers, chipsets, etc. Everything is up to date and I use an SSD as my main drive. It works perfectly in most cases but as soon as I use any kind of video streaming platform (HBO Go, Netflix, Youtube, etc.) my computer freezes at least 1 or 2 times a day. I purchased the SSD about 2 months ago so probably its good. I use it for working too, I usually work with huge 4k footages and other intense workloads and use it for gaming too. It works perfectly every single time no matter how heavy the workload is and how much time I spend on a game or video production software. The problem occurs just when I start to use video streaming sites and just when I use Google Chrome. With Firefox, Edge and even Opera, it works well but Chrome kills my PC. Is there any solution to fix this issue? I tried to reinstall everything in my PC but even with a fresh install Chrome can't handle the video streaming for more than 2-3 hours. I would love to change to another browser but only Chrome has the extensions I need so I would love to figure out what exactly causes the problem and find any possible solution.

Comment: Did you try to disable hardware acceleration on Chrome?

Comment: Not yet, I'll try out for a few days and give feedback

Comment: @CaldeiraG Well, I don't know why exactly but it works. With hardware acceleration off, the freezing disappeared. Thank you!

Comment: Nice to hear! :D you're welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try disabling 'Hardware acceleration' which can route video to the GPU. Also updating the video drivers can help.

Hardware acceleration can be disabled in Settings at the bottom, hit the button to show 'Advanced' and disable 'Use hardware acceleration when available' and relaunch browser. [More info here](https://www.howtogeek.com/412738/how-to-turn-hardware-acceleration-on-and-off-in-chrome/).

Comment: Hardware acceleration was indeed the problem. Sorry for the late reply.